# Расположить блок по середине, если не известна его ширина

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Всем привет.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с позиционированием по центру.
Есть блок, точная ширина которого не известна, задается контентом. По краям должны обрамлять две картинки, они же должны раздвигаться.

Пример [тут](http://biactors.ru)

Использовал фолаты для слияния и раздвижения, и выравнять такой блок по центру не получается.

Не покидает чувство, что что-то не так сделал, кажется, что можно проще, но не могу найти нужный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/aECvQ/1/) с CSS3 (множественные бэкграунды)

Внешний `div` занимает всю ширину и центрирует. Контент сидит в `display:inline-block', чтобы тот расширялся под содержание. Картинки рисуются бэкграундами в фоне бокового padding.

Comment: ОГРОООООООООМНОЕ Вам спасибо!!!!!!! Ваш совет очень помог!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Вот полная страница то что получилось, оба блок в центре выровнены таким способом. http://biactors.ru/interior.html

Answer (score 1):

Если устроит с Jquery, то примерно так наверное...

**HTML**

```
<div id="text">
    <div class="text">Text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#text {
    max-width: 600px;
}
.text {
    display: -moz-inline-stack; /* ← Firefox 2 backwards compatibility */
    display: inline-block;
    /* ↓ IE6 & IE7 «hasLayout» voodoo */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var widthDiv = $('.text').width();
    $('#text').css({'width' : widthDiv, 'margin' : '0 auto'});
});
```

Проверил, правда без правого и левого блока, все работает. Думаю и с блоками по бокам тоже сработает.

Comment: А если автор не хочет ограничениия в 600 px? Что если у заказчика не 15 дюймовый экран? Не поймите меня неправильно, ваше решение имеет место быть, но откуда вы берёт цифру 600 и зачем вам центрировать текст?

Comment: У автора вопроса в примере есть max-width и текст по середине...

Comment: Извиняюсь за 600px, это одна из проб.

Answer (score 0):

Как вы собираетесь выравнивать по центру то, что не ограничено никак по ширине? при таком условии текст будет шириной с viewport.

Comment: Это просто попытка сделать так чтобы бокс тянулся и был по центру и были две картинки.

Comment: я не могу представить то, что вы хотите сделать. Как можно центрировать блок который не имеет ограничений по ширине?

Comment: а если с помощью jquery узнать его ширину и добавлять ему после этого значение css width и margin?